# prove that $\frac{1}{x_1(1+x_1)}+ \frac{1}{x_2(1+x_2)}+...+\frac{1}{x_n(1+x_n)}\geqslant \frac{n}{2}$ by using AM-GM

Tags: inequality

The problem is:

> Set $x_1,x_2, ..., x_n >0$, and $x_1x_2\cdots x_n=1$. Prove that $$\frac{1}{x_1(1+x_1)}+ \frac{1}{x_2(1+x_2)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n(1+x_n)}\geqslant \frac{n}{2}.$$

I have already look at the solution but still very confused,
the first line said that

> OBVIOUSLY, the original inequality is equal to $$\frac{1+x_1+x_1^2}{x_1(1+x_1)}+\frac{1+x_2+x_2^2}{x_2(1+x_2)}+\cdots+\frac{1+x_n+x_n^2}{x_n(1+x_n)}\geqslant3n/2.$$

I am sorry that I am a dumb person, but I really can not find it is in any aspects "obvious", so i just calculate it:
since it said that "it is equal to", so I assume that it means that
1/3($\frac{1}{x_1(1+x_1)}+ \frac{1}{x_2(1+x_2)}+...+\frac{1}{x_n(1+x_n)}$)=
$\frac{1+x_1+x_1^2}{x_1(1+x_1)}+\frac{1+x_2+x_2^2}{x2(1+x_2)}+...+\frac{1+x_n+x_n^2}{x_n(1+x_n)}$
by simplifing the above equation I got that:
$1+x_i+x_i^2=3$, and I am stucked at here can not make any steps further.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1807033/42969 for some elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that we simply added $1$ to each of the $n$ fractions:

$$\frac{1}{x_k(1+x_k)} + 1 = \frac{1+x_k(1+x_k)}{x_k(1+x_k)} = \frac{1 + x_k + x_k^2}{x_k(1+x_k)}$$

There are $n$ of these fractions. Hence, doing this to the left hand side of the inequality is tantamount to adding $n$ to the right hand side of the inequality.